# Twilio Twiml use gather, say and redirect question

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-twiml

I am trying to loop through a  and give the customer 5 seconds then repeat prompt again, wait 5 seconds and after that redirect to my error handler. It is not clear how to do this in the documentation.

What I have found is the solutions to do  the  then  to my current url, but this will just loop continuously and not what we want. We need to stop after n number of times.

```
 gather.say(
        'Please enter or say your 10 Digit Account number.',
            {voice: 'alice', language: 'en-GB'}
    );

    gather.pause({
        length: 5
    });

    twiml.redirect({
        method: 'POST',
    }, '/ivr/wager/account');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are up to using Twilio Studio, there is an example using the Set Variable Widget as a counter along with Liquid Syntax, to increment the counter, otherwise you will need to maintain your own counter, which gets incremented, using a URL query parameter appended to your Redirect URL. See [Twilio Function](https://www.twilio.com/docs/runtime/functions) code below.

[Set Variables](https://www.twilio.com/docs/studio/widget-library/set-variables)

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  
  let twiml = new Twilio.twiml.VoiceResponse();
  let counter = event.count || 0;
  
  if (counter < 3) {
    counter ++;
    let gather = twiml.gather({action: `https://anonymous-1234.twil.io/gatherLoopCheck`, input: ' dtmf',
    timeout: 3,
    numDigits: 1})
    .say("Please enter a digit");
    twiml.redirect(`https://anonymous-1234.twil.io/gatherLoopCheck?count=${counter}`);
  return callback(null, twiml);
  } else {
    twiml.say("You've reached the limit!");
    return callback(null, twiml);
  }
};
```

Comment: Thank you. I wound up rolling my own due to some custom prompt messages, etc. But this was the solution.